# Marshal to JSON struct extended another struct with the same field label

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling

- I have 2 `struct` containing a field with the same label (`id`) and the same JSON annotation (`json:"id"`).
- One `struct` (`Bar`) includes the fields labels and their values from the other `struct` (`Foo`).

I would like to JSON marshal the wrapper `struct` `Bar` with both the `id` fields, but the inner one with a different JSON annotation (e.g. `json:"foo_id"`). I can not find a way to do it, but it looks like something that should be doable?

Having a quick look here https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/ I can not find the solution.

Is it possible at all? Is there any work around?
I am trying to avoid all the boiler plate of get/set to copy/paste values between structs, I hope this is doable somehow.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Stuff string `json:"stuff"`
}

type Bar struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Foo
    // the following does not work, 
    // I've tried a few variations with no luck so far
    // Foo.ID int `json:"foo_id"`
    OtherStuff string `json:"other_stuff"`
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{ID: 123, Stuff: "abc" }
    bar := Bar{ID: 456, OtherStuff: "xyz", Foo: foo }

    fooJsonStr, _ := json.Marshal(foo)
    barJsonStr, _ := json.Marshal(bar)

    fmt.Printf("Foo: %s\n", fooJsonStr)
    fmt.Printf("Bar: %s\n", barJsonStr)
}
```

Gives this output:

```
Foo: {"id":123,"stuff":"abc"} 
Bar: {"id":456,"stuff":"abc","other_stuff":"xyz"}
```

Comment: If you change the tag of any of the ID fields (to e.g. `\`json:"id2"\``), both will end up in the JSON. Is that not good enough?

Comment: Not sure why people downvotes this question providing no feedback at all. Anyway @icza yes, that would work, but I hoped I did not have to change the JSON marshalling labels of the inner struct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One struct (Bar) inherit from the other struct (Foo).

Obviously not as there is no inheritance in Go.

If yout want Foo's ID to be named foo_id:

```
type Foo struct {
    ID int `json:"foo_id"`
    Stuff string `json:"stuff"`
}
```

Dead simple.

Comment: Thanks, I've amended the question to better suite the Go terminology. Is there a way to avoid changing the JSON marshalling rules for `Foo`? But doing something in `Bar` to achieve this same result you suggest?

Comment: @TPPZ How should that work? Wher in the documentation of encoding/json did you find any hint that this might be possible? Why should this be possible at all? You serialize Foo. How Foo is serialized is governed by Foo not by Bar. This is not encoding/xml. If it's not documented that you can do this then it is not possible. No magic here.

Comment: You look so sure about this topic that you deserve your answer to be accepted as it provides a dead simple solution.